# Can someone explain why I cant put br tags inside a table

Tags: html

The line break appears above the the table, not were I would normally expect it to be. I'm just wondering why this is.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>cell group 1</th><!--<br> this wouldnt work-->
            <td>cell 1</td>
            <td>cell 2</td>
            <td>cell 3</td>
            <td>cell 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>cell group 2</th>   
            <td>cell 5</td>
            <td>cell 5</td>
            <td>cell 6</td>
            <td>cell 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>cell group 3</th>
            <td>cell 8</td>
            <td>cell 9</td>
            <td>cell 10</td>
            <td>cell 11</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Because that would be invalid HTML? You're attempting to make a `<br>` element a child of a `<tr>` which isn't allowed. Only `<th>` or `<td>` can be children of a `<tr>`.

Comment: where do you expect it to be? I'm unclear on what a line break should look like, within a table row, outside of a cell

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put a `<br>` tag inside a table structure. But you can do it inside cell elements: `<th>` or `<td>`.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>cell group 1<br></th>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2<br></td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>cell group 2</th>   
        <td>cell 5</td>
        <td>cell 5</td>
        <td>cell 6</td>
        <td>cell 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>cell group 3</th>
        <td>cell 8</td>
        <td>cell 9</td>
        <td>cell 10</td>
        <td>cell 11</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The visual content of a table can only exist inside table data cell tags (`td` or `th`) - putting elements in between these makes no logical sense - where would it appear?

If you have some tabular data and want to put something **between** two data cells, then it just becomes another data cell, doesn't it.

If you want to adjust the visual appearance of some part of a table, it should be done with CSS margin or padding styles, not by adding line breaks (this applies in general - `br` should not be used to adjust the size of elements.)

Comment: I know line brakes shouldn't be used I'm just experimenting to better understand it. its still not working strangely, an hr tag will work but a br tag will not